# How to add new parameters to url without refreshing page in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I work in react and I have a shop page that have some filters. When I apply a filter, I want to also add this filter into the url but without reloading page.

I mean like this :

```
currentUrl : something.com
newUrl : something.com/brand-nike
```

I want to change url without refresh.

I already tried these codes but both reload page :

```
window.history.pushState({ path: url }, "", url);

window.history.replaceState(null, "", url);
```

And also I am using `react-router-dom` for routing.

This is my `App.js` :

```
return (
      <ToastProvider>
        <ShopFilterContext.Provider value={shopFilterHook}>
          <CartContext.Provider value={cartHook}>
            <React.Fragment>
              <Router basename={BASENAME}>{renderRoutes(routes)}</Router>
            </React.Fragment>
          </CartContext.Provider>
        </ShopFilterContext.Provider>
      </ToastProvider>
    );
```

This is `renderRoutes` function :

```
export const renderRoutes = (routes = []) => {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
      <Switch>
        {routes.map((route, i) => {
          const Guard = route.guard || Fragment;
          const Layout = route.layout || Fragment;
          const Component = route.component;
          return (
            <Route
              key={i}
              path={route.path}
              exact={route.exact}
              render={(props) => {
                props["layoutObj"] = route.layoutObj;
                return (
                  <Guard>
                    <Layout>{route.routes ? renderRoutes(route.routes) : <Component {...props} />}</Layout>
                  </Guard>
                );
              }}
            />
          );
        })}
      </Switch>
    </Suspense>
  );
};
```

And this is `routes` variable

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/account/*",
    layout: NifsyLayout,
    routes: [
      {
        exact: true,
        path: "/account/*",
        component: lazy(() => import("./pages/MyAccount")),
      },
      {
        path: "/account/*",
        exact: true,
        component: () => <Redirect to={ACCOUNT_URL} />,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: "/search/*",
    layout: NifsyLayout,
    routes: [
      {
        exact: true,
        path: "/search/*",
        component: lazy(() => import("./pages/Shop")),
      },
      {
        path: "/search/*",
        exact: true,
        component: () => <Redirect to={ACCOUNT_URL} />,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: "*",
    layout: NifsyLayout,
    routes: [
      {
        exact: true,
        path: "/not-found",
        component: lazy(() => import("./pages/NotFound")),
      },
      {
        path: "*",
        exact: true,
        component: () => <Redirect to={BASE_URL} />,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

And this is for navigation : (history is hook from `useHistory`)

```
let url = "/search";

if (filter.category) url = url + "/" + filter.category;

if (filter.brands) {
  for (let i = 0; i < filter.brands.length; i++) {
    url = url + filter.brands[i];
  }
}

if (filter.collections) {
  for (let i = 0; i < filter.collections.length; i++) {
    url = url + filter.collections[i];
  }
}

url = url + "?q=" + filter.keyword;
url = url + "&start=" + filter.start;
url = url + "&size=" + filter.size;
url = url + "&sortby=" + filter.sort;
url = url + "&filter=" + (typeof filter.filters == "string" ? filter.filters : JSON.stringify(filter.filters));
// multi refresh
//window.history.pushState({ path: url }, "", url);

//window.history.replaceState(null, "Nifsy", url);

history.push(url);
```

Comment: Can you clarify the use case? What does "add new parameters to url without refreshing page" mean?

Comment: Are you just trying to navigate from "/" to "/brand-nike"? Please share your routing code and the code where you are trying to do the navigation. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Why are you trying to render multiple routes on the same path? If your search paths are exactly `"/search/*"` with a trailing slash, then you can never match `"/search"` with query parameters. I don't see any issue with how you compute the `url`, so I suspect your components just aren't looking for route changes once mounted. Where you doing the navigation from? We still need a more comprehensive code example.

Comment: actually my search path may differ based on different filters, `/search/category-women/` or `/search/category-women/brand-nike/collection-winter/`

Comment: In this case you may want a path more like `"/search/:category/:brand/:collection"` so you can access the various path segments of the URL. You should also note that `react-router-dom` route match params ***are not*** the same thing as URL queryString parameters. See [handling query parameters](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters).

Comment: So my original problem that was changing url without reloading page is related to my routing ?

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by "add new parameters to url without refreshing page"?

Comment: I want to change url without refreshin page

Comment: I don't understand why you'd need to refresh the page in order to change the URL, you can just push to new routes, the URL will update.

Comment: I want when user selected a new brand to filter by, I made changes to search result and change the url to mention this new brand. But changing this url with history.pushState cause my page to reload and I don't want this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236341/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-obtice).

Answer (score 2):

It might be late to answer but I searched a lot and tried various alternatives. Finally what worked for me :
`window.history.replaceState("", "",`/new_path`);`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using functional components and the react router, from **react-router-dom** you can import the hook **useHistory**.

```
const history = useHistory();
history.push("/your/path");
// or
history.replace("/your/path");
```

Answer (score -1):

To not reloading you have to design your Route and define your path here . this will help you to get the page without loading .

Comment: <Switch>
<Route exact path="/">
<ShirtList />
</Route>
<switch>